# 2 divs side by side, each 50%, same height

Tags: html, css

I would like to place two divs within a container side by side and - thanks to SO - I feel I'm almost there, but there is something I really don't understand.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="parent">    
 <div class="font" id="left"></div>
 <div class="font" id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS looks like this:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#left {
    width: 50%;
    background: lightblue;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
#right {
    width: 50%;
    background: orange;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
.parent{
    font-size:0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 40px;
}
.font{
    font-size:16px;
}
```

font-size needs to be 0 to account for the whitespaces. display is set at inline-block (I'd rather use display than float).

This works fine. It keeps working when I add content to **both** the left and the right block. However, when I add content to only one block, this block gets strangely offset from the top. It's like adding margin-top: 50px or something. And I don't get why.

Here's the JSFiddle with content in the left block: https://jsfiddle.net/dave_s/phon1tws/

I've also tried overflow:hidden, but that shrinks the block with the content.

Any help would be much appreciated! Also if someone could explain to me what happens here, that'd be really great!

Thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 16):

One way is do use flexbox. [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BygVdN). Note the [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) for flexbox and use prefixes.

```
.parent {
   display: flex;
}
```

Comment: I had to add `width: 100%` on `.parent` for this to work in my case if that can help someone.

Answer (score 3):

add this in css

```
#left, #right{float:left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use CSS tables.  Your mark-up lends itself nicely to the technique.

The main advantage is that you don't have to alter the font sizes to compensate for the white space that can show up between inline blocks.

Having said that, both approaches will work in your situation.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
#left, #right {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
#left {
  background: lightblue;
}
#right {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="font" id="left">Left Blue</div>
  <div class="font" id="right">Right Orange</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this really nice guide about Flexbox. Nowadays it's the clearest way to build a layout.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
.font {
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

By default **baseline**s are vertically aligned. If the `<div>` is empty, its bottom line will be its baseline. Otherwise the baseline of the first line of text is the baseline to be aligned with.

This problem exists even when there are words in both `<div>`s but having different `font-size`s.